# disable / enable asp.net linkbutton using javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, validation

I need to be able to enable and disable a linkbutton using javascript as part of a custom validator that I'm writing.

I discovered that setting "disabled=true" will disable a standard button, but it does nothing to a linkbutton.

After mucking about in JQuery I discovered that the following will actually disable the button:

```
$(button).click( function() { return false; }
```

Where button is a reference to the object. That works well. However, I can't for the life of me work out how to re-enable it! Neither of these seem to work:

```
$(button).click( function() { return true; }
$(button).click( function() { }
```

If anyone could either point me in the right direction to re-enable my button, or suggest a better way of disabling the button, It'd be appreciated.

Chers,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to unbind the first event first.

Don't know in other versions, but in 1.4.2 you can attach multiple events, so the behaviour when you do this

```
$(button).click( function() { return false; } 
$(button).click( function() { return true; }
```

will be 'return false;return true;'

```
$(button).unbind('click');
$(button).click( function() { return true; }
```

Comment: This is right, but $(button).click( function() { return true; }  isn't neccesary, with the .unbind("click") is enough